# Select with fields to include in detail table with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I select whitch fields should be included for detail table in EF Core.
I tried with this query:

```
    var result= this.context.MainTable
        .Include(t => t.DetailTable)
        .Select(t => new {
            id = t.Id,
            values = t.DetailTable.Select(t2 => t2.SomeField)
        })
        .ToArray();
```

I would expect this result to single query, but it does not. It automatically execute query one by one for every row in MainTable and select SomeField.

Comment: Most likely this is EF Core bug (there are many). Stay updated with their latest releases until they fix it :-(

Comment: Not sure you need the Include...

Comment: Which EF Core version??

Comment: I use EF Core 1.1.2.

Comment: Share your model. Is `DetailTable` navigation reference type or collection type? As @ErikEJ said, you don't need include.

Comment: It is a known issue and it will be fixed in EF Core 2.1 according to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4007).